# Can I implement something similar to iOS "Folders"?

Tags: iphone

I am going to make something that very visually similar to iOS4 folders but it's not folders at all )))

For example, I have 4 labels on screen - see sketch. Screen splits, if user click on label. Other lebels going down and we can see some text between splited views. If user click once more - view back to "normal" state as before. And so on.

Questions are:

1. is it confront iPhone HIG and app can be rejected?
2. what is the easiest way to implement this?

thanks )

[alt text http://a.imageshack.us/img196/1306/sketch1.gif](http://a.imageshack.us/img196/1306/sketch1.gif)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your App can *always* be rejected, for no reason at all.

This seems less like folders and more like an outline with collapsable items (or code folding in a programming editor).  Plenty of outliner like apps in the store so no reason you should be able to do this (but read the first line of this answer again! No promises!).

Lots of ways to implement this.  Here's a random quick one: If you use a `UITableView` and then have a `UITableViewDataSource` implementing class that has items marked as hidden/vislble.  Then your `numberOfRowsInSection` method could return only the number of visible rows and the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` would have to skip hidden rows (this might be too slow if you have many items - if so, cache visible count, use secondary array of indexes (or `NSMutableIndexSet`) of visible items, etc).