# iOS safari-esque folders

Tags: objective-c, ios, safari, directory

I am not asking for springboard [folders](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332121/can-i-implement-something-similar-to-ios-folders), but rather the "folders" in the bookmarks popover of the safari app.  I have no idea how this is implemented (strings in files, keys in dictionaries, file system representation, etc.) and am very interested in if someone had been able to make something like it.  Can someone point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you could implement them however you want.

Personally I would use plists and have nsarrays that can be within nsarrays.

However I can think of a way to do it with sqlite3 databases, or even physical files (although that could start to get out of hand)

What kind of data do you want to be stored in these folders?

If just strings I would suggest something in a plist/xml format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>folders</key>
<array>
    <string>afolder1</string>
    <string>afolder2</string>
</array>
</dict>
```

Comment: Just files or links to files (mostly the latter).  Now that I think about it, it's most likely plists.  Thanks.